# How to suppress warning on PaperTrail gem with Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, paper-trail-gem

> DEPRECATION WARNING: PaperTrail.track_associations has not been set. As of PaperTrail 5, it defaults to false. Tracking associations is an experimental feature so we recommend setting PaperTrail.config.track_associations = false in your config/initializers/paper_trail.rb . (called from require at /Users/george/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68)
>   Run options:

Since this is not a Rails app, there is no `config/initializers/paper_trail.rb`. Looked at `https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/generators/paper_trail/install_generator.rb`, but didn't see a generator for the config file.

If I do

```
require 'paper_trail'
PaperTrail.config.track_associations = false
```

it still emits the warning.

Also tried:

```
def PaperTrail; end
PaperTrail.config.track_associations = false
require 'paper_trail'
```

This is a "Classic" Sinatra app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is due the the call to `require 'paper_trail'` initializing a `PaperTrail.config` object: [this](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail.rb#L187) line results in [this](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/version_concern.rb) file getting required, [a part of which](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/version_concern.rb#L19-L21) gets executed resulting in initializing the `config` singleton. We can solve this by first setting up the config object and then requiring the top-level `paper_trail` file later.

```
# app.rb

require 'sinatra'
require 'paper_trail/config'

config = PaperTrail::Config.instance
config.track_associations = true

# require models here
Dir["#{Dir.pwd}/models/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }

# rest of app code
```

And the models won't need any change:

```
# models/article.rb

require 'paper_trail'

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end
```

Thus, when the `require 'paper_trail'` call gets executed, we already have the correct configuration setup and the warning won't be displayed.

Comment: I created a barebones app https://github.com/kgrz/37797571 and checked out Papertrail's code. And lots of `puts` driven debugging :D

Comment: Wow, that was a major job. Thank you!!! At least I know how to figure it out next time.

Answer (score 1):

I added `PaperTrail.config.track_associations = false` to `config/application.rb` in the definition of `class Application`.